# How maven handle version for children jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have multi module maven project. Where inside of parem `pom.xml` I am setting up version in properites tag for let's say `log4j-core` library.
And inside of children (let's call it child.jar) I am adding log4j as dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

without a version, so after running `dependency:tree` that log4j has correct version taken from parent `pom.xml` file. So here everything is working ok for me.

But I would like to reuse this `child.jar` in my spring boot project, but there I didnt write in parent pom version for log4j. And so after running dependency:tree I can see that version is wrong.
I can see that spring-boot-starter is including `log4j-to-slf4j` but with different version, and for some reason my log4j-core has the same version as included jars from spring boot.

So my question is, shouldnt my child.jar has the version from my first project set up for log4j? Or do I need to specificly say version for log4j inside of child.jar?

Comment: Just define the dependency of log4j in your spring boot project which overrides the one given by spring boot...

Answer (score 1):

If the version is omitted it's indirectly inherited from the parent. If you import your child module in another project it will indirectly inherit parent's version of log4j-core.

Define version in *dependencyManagement* tag or in *dependency* tag in parent/child module of your project.